# Are these compatible bottom brackets?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a LeMond Big Sky SLT & an Opus Triton. Every bikepedia-esque site I went on said they had incompatible bottom brackets.

When I actually read the brackets today the LeMond has a BSA. The Opus only states: BC1.37x24.

BSA has the same measurements: 1.37x24 (according to wikipedia.)

Does this mean the crank from one will fit in the other or am I missing something?

I've read a lot about all the crank differences and compatibility issues etc but frankly I can't identify what I have to know if they're different.

Comment: The BB's are both ISO threaded. You still need to know if the crank is splined or square tapered and the spindle length of the BB - see the Shimano cartridge bottom bracket section of http://sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html for details. "As far as crank interchangeability is concerned, the most important thing is the overall length, and the offset if the spindle is longer on one side than the other (that's true of many older units.)"

Comment: So it is a Splined crank. The length of the BB's both measure 91mm.

Comment: It looks like the ISIS Splined crank on Sheldons page.

Comment: I think I'm just highly confused about what is what. Only now am I realizing that the spindle is considered part of the BB  and not part of the crank. I removed the spindle still attached to the drive side of the crank and thought I could just move the crank with spindle into the other bottom bracket (same 91mm length) without issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have, but you may want to go to your local bike co-op or bike shop or something to see what you have and stuff. Alternatively, you may want to look at a book like  "Bicycling Magazine's Complete Guide to Bicycle Maintenance and Repair" by Todd Downs for some details. Why do you want to swap the cranks anyway?

Comment: The LeMond bike frame and forks are cracked. I had an accident 4 months back. The Opus is a replacement frame I'm moving components to. If both the BB are 91mm in length and are both BSA would they not me interchangeable. Then I can keep the BB and crank from the LeMond but move it into the Opus frame together?

Comment: I really think you should just take the cranks and bike to your LBS and then find a BB that fits, if you haven't replaced a BB before. You'll need some supplies which are a bit specialized (BB tool and/or possibly a specialized type of wrench) and don't really pay off unless you're replacing multiple bottom brackets, so you may want to let them put it in. There are multiple types of splined cranks, so you need to match that as well.

Comment: In most cases a "cartridge" is used for the bottom bracket bearing, and that "cartridge" includes the actual crank shaft, and they normally cannot be separated (without a hacksaw).  The cartridge may or may not have a threaded retaining cup fixed to one end (vs having two removable cups).  Crank shafts come with 4-5 different end styles, the old round cottered style, the standard square style, and 2-3 (maybe 4) different splined styles.  The cartridges differ in length and "offset" (asymmetry), based on the number of chainrings, et al.  And we haven't even discussed external bearing BBs.

Answer (score 1):

Matching BB is one of the hardest jobs as a paper exercise compared to eyeballing them side by side.  As suggest in @Batman comment, length and offset are both critical, yet most sellers only specify length.

As far as matching Cranks go, there are a  number of systems - square taper was (an probably still is) the most common - there is some confusion over the compatibility between a couple of different standards, but it does not seem to be a problem in reality. Spline cranks come in a couple of different flavors, which are incompatible. Have a read of Sheldons webpage on the subject.